# Consulta error: mysqli_num_rows() espera que el parámetro 1 sea mysqli_result

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

buen dia tengo configurado mi hosting por medio de remoto dentro de la misma red
mi problema es que al momento de iniciar sesion me manda el siguiente error en mi codigo

```
Advertencia : mysqli_num_rows() espera que el parámetro 1 sea mysqli_result, bool dado en C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ convenios \ SERVICES \ verificar.php en la línea 23 cadena (66) "SELECCIONE nivelado de usuarios DONDE usuario = 'Rmendoza' AND clave = '123' "
```

cosa que la conexion a todo si es exitosa

pero no puedo conectarme con la bd
cave mencionar que mi BD esta en mi maquina y xampp lo tengo habilitado en otra maquina de otro piso

```
<?php

include("configuracion.php");
/*$sql_connection = new mysqli('localhost:4437','root','','convenios');*/

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Error connecting to database. ".mysqli_connect_error();
}
session_start();

$usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['usuario']);
$Password = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['Password']);

if (!$usuario || !$Password) {
    echo "Both fields must be filled out.";
    return;
}

$query = "SELECT levely from useros WHERE usuario='$usuario' AND clave='$Password'";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

$rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($rows == 1) {
    // Leer consulta
    $datos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    // Comparar dato
    if($datos['levely'] == 2) {
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
        header("Location: admin.php");
    } else {
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
        header("Location:index1.php");
    }
    // Finalizar ejecución de script
    exit;
} 

else {
    
    
 var_dump($query);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fijate bien la consulta SQL... estás poniendo como nombre de la tabla `useros`. Eso hace que falle la consulta, y por eso `mysqli_num_rows` te tira el mensaje de error.